# What is a convenient way to keep track of alchemical formulae?

Tags: iron-kingdoms

I am playing in an Iron Kingdoms campaign as a Gobber Alchemist/ Guttersnipe called Dr. Fizzbang! I'm really enjoying all the possibilities being an alchemist entails, but there seems like a lot to keep track of.

As well as the formulae listed in the core rulebook, new options are added in the Urban adventure and frequently in No Quarter magazines too. It's becoming difficult to keep track of my character and what he can create and what components are available. Are there any convenient ways to keep track and gather together all of these recipes and components?

P.S I'm looking for solutions which don't rely on electronics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is a set of cards or sheets of paper, depending on how much information you need to store for each formula. If you keep them in alphabetical order, and have a list somewhere of all the formula cards you currently have, then it's fairly easy to select a specific one when you want it. To get the formulae on the cards, you can either write them out by hand (this has the benefit of helping you memorise at least a vague outline of what each formula does) or using a copier to copy from the source materials to the cards.

One great thing about using cards or sheets of paper is that you can make duplicates of your most-used formulae and keep them on hand, while having another copy in the main bank of cards.